# How to set up MySQLi connection on Godaddy hosting?

Tags: mysqli, godaddy-api

Has anyone had success with MySQLi in Godaddy?
If so, are any additional steps required so that it will work?

MySQL, on the otherhand, seems to work with no problems.

```
 define('DBHOST', 'localhost');
 define('DBUSER', 'username');
 define('DBPASS', 'pass');
 define('DBNAME', 'databasename');
 $conn = mysqli_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DBNAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

The default php version did not include mysqli

You have to go into settings and upgrade the php to the lastest version. This version will include mysqli and allow you to use it.